# wolfram 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
async def oracle(ctx, *, args):
    async with ctx.typing():
        app_id = userappid
        clientss = wolframalpha.Client(app_id)
        res = clientss.query(args)
        answer = (next(res.results).text)
        embed2322 = discord.Embed(
            title = "",
            description= f"**Question:** {args}\n**Answer:** {answer}",
            color = discord.Colour.gold()
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed2322)
```

error: `raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'text'`

this is being run in replit.com though...
cant seem to find the solution for this error I get can anyone help me with it please

Comment: Try `answer = (await next(res.results)).text`

Comment: it gave me the same error

Comment: Was the error message the same though?

Comment: Yes same error...